# MySQL vs Cassandra for read intensive web service on AWS ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have a MySQL DB with approax 40million rows (37 GB data including indexes). The task which are performed on DB, are mainly reads and once in every month or two, the DB would be updated. I want the query latency to be NOT more than 50ms. I am confused b/w Cassandra and MySQL so looking for some guidance considering the following aspects.

1.) The queries will not have any 'JOINS' but it can be on multiple fields with optionally containing 'OR' clause. The primary key doesn't have single field but many.
the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM routes
WHERE origin='XYZ' AND (destination='ABC' OR destination='PQR')
AND startTime <= '14:00:00' AND startTime >= '10:00:00'
AND flight=false AND monday=true
```

2.) The DB will be hosted on ec2. The cost, scalability and fault tolerance (ie number of replicas) are major concerns too. Assuming 50 queries/sec, please suggest the number of instances and ec2 instance-types, I should go for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Definitely use cassandra if you do not need joins.
2. if cost is a concern, EC2 is really pricy for what it has to offer. You can easily get servers at 4x performance for half the cost, you could lok at thinks like hetzner or hosteurope.
3. If speed is an issue, avoid EC2 altogether, and try to get a proper server, not virtual instances. Or at least virtual instances from a host where not everything runs as slow as syrup. 37gb is not much for a single good server for which you'D end up paying 40-60 euro per month
4. On that size of flat data mysql would perform rather poorly. Postgres would be the better free sql option, but NOSQL would win performance wise.